# PHP Oracle Query Data Based On Array Data in Table

Tags: php, oracle

I have 2 tables in Oracle db.

t_master_cp

```
cp_id | cp_name
1     | eat
2     | play
3     | run
4     | sleep
```

t_choose_cp

```
form_no | uid | cp_id
1       | 1   | 3,4
2       | 2   | 1,3,4
3       | 3   | 1,2,3
```

Now I want to query the data into PHP programming and this is my code so far:

```
$uid = "1";
$q_get_choose_cp = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM t_choose_cp WHERE uid = '$uid'");
oci_execute($q_get_choose_cp);
$d_get_choose_cp = oci_fetch_array($q_get_choose_cp);
$get_cp = $d_get_choose_cp['cp_id'];

$q_data = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM t_master_cp WHERE cp_id IN '$get_cp'");
oci_execute($q_data);
while($d_data = oci_fetch_array($q_data))
{
     $get_cp_name = $d_data['cp_name'];
     ?>

     <div><?php echo $get_cp_name; ?></div>
<?php
}
```

When run the query, the result is empty and got error : `Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01722: invalid number in...`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$uid = 1;
$q_get_choose_cp = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM t_choose_cp WHERE uid = $uid");
```

No need to quote the value if the datatype in your table is number.

then:

```
$get_cp = '('.implode(',',$d_get_choose_cp['cp_id']).')';
```

That will give you a query like:
"SELECT * FROM t_master_cp WHERE cp_id IN (1,2,3)"

Hope that works for you.